# Azure Form Recognizer Generic error during prediction

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I've been using azure form recognizer for a few months now, and I'm overall quite happy with it, but today we've run into a problem which doesn't really hint as to what the problem is:

```
"analyzeResult": {
                    "errors": [
                        {
                            "code": "3014",
                            "message": "Generic error during prediction."
                        }
                    ],
                    "version": "2.0.0"
                },
                "createdDateTime": "2020-07-27T16:35:17Z",
                "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-07-27T16:36:20Z",
                "status": "failed"
```

It seems to happen with *TIFF*, *PNG* but I have not tested it with *PDF*. The image quality is very high in all cases, and it really can't be explained easily.

Has anyone run into this before, and was there a solution to it?

Comment: This error could indicate that the OCR timed out or your image or file is password protected. Since a PDF was not used it is most likely an OCR issue, if there is no response in 60 seconds. Can you retry or check with image of a slightly lower quality?

Comment: @RohitMungi-MSFT Hi, I'm uploading `TIFF` images, obtained from PDF at 300DPI. Would that explain why it times out? Is there a way to detect time-outs like with Azure OCR? I've tried with 150DPI, 200DPI, 250DPI and 300DPI, both PNG and TIFF

Comment: Currently the backend timeouts are not shown or the user would not know about them. Is it possible to share these images if not confidential? Would like to run these through our team to check further.

Comment: @RohitMungi-MSFT I'll need to ask permission for that, and sadly I have been discarding them until now. I'll let you know as soon as I get a reply.

Comment: @RohitMungi-MSFT I've got permission to share them, if you could let me know how to do so in private manner, I'm more than happy to send samples over.

Comment: You can address me and email us at `AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com` with the link to this thread and files attached.

Comment: Just want to check if this problem was resolved?

Comment: @XinZou I am no longer working on this so I can't really answer the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I had to update the nuget package from 3.1.0-beta.1 to 3.1.0-beta.4 and then it worked.